# Managing backstack in Android Navigation Component : NavDestination id not matching with fragment id from navgraph xml

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I have one entry fragment (MainFragment) and 5 other fragments in 1 particular flow in my Android app. The navigation between these fragments is non-linear and user can land on any fragment depending on the response. I am using `findNavController().navigate(R.id.feagmentX)` instead of using actions.

I need to implement custom logic to show a confirmation dialog if the previous fragment in the backstack is the MainFragment. To achieve this, I am using `findNavController().previousBackStackEntry.destination.id` and checking it with `R.id.fragmentMain` which refers to the navigation graph XML file. However, these IDs are not matching.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentMain"
    android:name="com.example.fragmentMain"
    ...
>
```

What is the correct way to do this? Should I add a tag for these fragments in the XML and check equality for the tag, or is there any other approach that I should follow?

Ideally the id approach should work right?

Comment: So if you log `findNavController().previousBackStackEntry.destination`, what does it print?

Comment: Int. it prints the id of the destination.

Comment: That's actually not what I asked. I asked if you print the entire `destination`, what does it say.

Comment: @ianhanniballake It prints - Destination(com.a.b:id/fragmentMain) class=com.a.b.registration.view.FragmentMain

Comment: So the ID is equal to `com.a.b.R.id.fragmentMain`?

Comment: no, it is not equal to R.id.fragmentMain.

Comment: Again, that's not actually what I asked. I asked if it is equal to `com.a.b.R.id.fragmentMain`.

Comment: not sure what you are referring to. findNavController().previousBackStackEntry.destination.id prints 2131296519 and R.id.fragmentMain prints 1000315

Answer (score 0):

Can't we show popup when there is only 1 fragment in backstack as mentioned below

```
navHostFragment.childFragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener {
            if (navHostFragment.childFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount == 1) {
                // only 1 fragment left , show popup
            } else {
                // there are fragments in backstack
            }
        }
```

Comment: this will solve for some scenarios. i am trying to identify the the previous fragment in the backstack